# Why is one version of this code so much faster than the other

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to improve some code I did not write, mostly to make it easier for other people to understand (I found it to be really weirdly written).  I attempted to rewrite it, and it does basically the same thing, using roughly the same processes.

However the old one takes 2 minutes to run with some data I recorded.  The other takes well over an hour to work on the same data.  What on earth is going on?

The data format they work on is:

[image: Sample Data]

Edit: I should add, I would use dictionaries, as I think they would be fastest, except the number of "TextX" is basically random.  Sometimes only Text1 appears.  Sometimes it goes all the way to Text20, or more.

(sorry for impending wall of code, and sorry if I got the image link format wrong - never done that before)

Old code:

> ```
> sub DivideSheet()
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
> Dim name As String
> Dim point_name As String
> Dim SheetCount, sheetNumber As Integer
> Dim RowCount, RowStart As Long
> Dim Exist, RowEmpty As Boolean
>
> Sheets("RAW DATA").Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
>     FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(27, 1), _
>     Array(31, 1), Array(36, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
>
> Exist = False
> RowCount = 1
> RowStart = 1
> SheetCount = 1
> point_name = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 3)
>
> For RowCount = 1 To 1048576                                       'loop through all the rows in the sheet
>
>     If CStr(Sheets(1).Cells(RowCount, 3)) = "" Then             'If the cell isnt a new transmition
>                                                                 'do nothing
>     ElseIf CStr(Sheets(1).Cells(RowCount, 3)) = point_name Then   'If the new transmition is from the same node
>                                                                 'Do nothing
>     Else                                                        'If its a new node
>
>         For SheetCount = 1 To Sheets.Count                      'loop through sheets
>
>             If Worksheets(SheetCount).name = point_name Then      'If the sheet name matches point_name
>                 Exist = True                                    'set flag to true
>                 sheetNumber = SheetCount                        'Record Sheet number
>                 Exit For                                        'Exit the for loop
>             End If
>
>         Next SheetCount
>
>         If Exist = False Then                                   'If the Node didnt have a sheet
>             sheetNumber = SheetCount
>             Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(SheetCount - 1)    'Create a sheet
>             Worksheets(Sheets.Count).name = point_name            'Name it for the RTU
>         End If
>
>         Call CopyLine(sheetNumber, RowStart, RowCount - 1)      'Call the Copying function to copy the chunk of data
>
>         RowStart = RowCount                                     'Set a new start point for the next chunk of data
>
>         point_name = Worksheets(1).Cells(RowCount, 3)             'Set the Node the chunk of data will belong to
>
>         SheetCount = 1                                          'Reset Variable
>         Exist = False                                           'Reset Variable
>
>
>     End If
>
> Next RowCount
>
> SheetCount = 1                                                  'Resets the SheetCount Variable
>
>
> For SheetCount = 1 To Sheets.Count                              'Loops through Sheets
>
>     Sheets(SheetCount).Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit      'Autofits the H column
>
> Next SheetCount
>
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub CopyLine(sheetNumber As Integer, RowStart As Long, rowNumber As Long)
>
>     If Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("A1").Value = "" Then           'If its the first data to enter the sheet
>                                                                     'Copy the chunk of data
>         Sheets(1).Range("a" & RowStart, "h" & rowNumber).Copy _
>         Destination:=Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("A1", Cells(rowNumber - RowStart + 1, "H"))
>
>     ElseIf Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("H2").Value = "" Then       'If its the Second data to enter the sheet
>                                                                     'Copy the chunk of data
>         Sheets(1).Range("a" & RowStart, "h" & rowNumber).Copy _
>         Destination:=Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("A2", Cells(rowNumber - RowStart + 2, "H"))
>
>     Else                                                            'otherwise
>                                                                     'Copy the chunk of data
>        Sheets(1).Range("a" & RowStart, "h" & rowNumber).Copy _
>        Destination:=Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("h1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -7)
>
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

and my code...

```
sub DivideSheet()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Point As String

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

wb1.Sheets("RAW DATA").Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(27, 1), _
    Array(31, 1), Array(36, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'loop through all the rows in the sheet
For i = 1 To wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Point = wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
    If wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
        a = sheetexists(Point)
            If a Then
                Call CopyLine(a, i, Point)
            Else
                wb1.Sheets.Add after:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = Point
                Call CopyLine(wb1.Sheets.Count, i, Point)
                wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(1).Delete
            End If
    End If
Next i

For Each wsh In wb1.Sheets              'Loops through Sheets
    wsh.Columns.AutoFit         'Autofits everything
Next wsh

End Sub

Public Sub CopyLine(a, i, Point)

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
j = i + 1
While (wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = "" Or wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = Point) And j <= wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb1.Sheets(1).Rows(i)) = 0
    j = j + 1
Wend

wb1.Sheets(1).Range(wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1), wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j - 1, 8)).Copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(a).Cells(wb1.Sheets(a).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0)
i = j - 1
End Sub

Function sheetexists(Point)
Dim a As Integer
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

sheetexists = 0
For a = 1 To wb1.Sheets.Count
    If wb1.Sheets(a).name = Point Then
        sheetexists = a
        Exit Function
    End If
Next a

End Function
```

I'm not crazy, right?  There is no fundamental difference between these two, other than mine being fewer lines, less circuitous, and generally not being wasteful?  So why is my new code taking so much longer?

Comment: seems like a better question for Code Review.

Comment: Oh.  I have never heard of that place, I will move it there now.  Sorry!

Comment: no problem! Since both of these code are *working*, seems like your question is much more about optimization methods, than actually solving a specific problem (runtime error, compile error, wrong output, etc.). Cheers!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should type the variables in your functions/subroutine signatures, that's certainly going to be a factor though I'm not sure how much of one. Also, there are easy ways to optimize your `SheetExists` function with an error-handler. `Function SheetExists(sName$): Dim w as Worksheet: On Error Resume Next: Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName): SheetExists = w Is Not Nothing: End Sub`

Comment: I can see how that would be faster, but I was under the impression using errors like that was considered bad practice, even if it was easy or efficient or whatever.  So I was trying not to do that.  Thank you, though.

Comment: It's pretty common in simple cases like that where you can easily isolate the error and don't need to rely on spaghetti code of `GoTo` and `Resume` statements. But *generally* it's to be avoided unless you know what you're doing (I think the advice is aimed mostly at people who use `On Error Resume Next` without fully understanding the implications of that).

Comment: David was also referring to your parameters being all implicitly `Variant` - your version incurs implicit conversion overhead, which certainly affects performance to a degree. IOW instead of `Function sheetexists(Point)` you should have `Function sheetexists(ByVal Point As String) As Long`.

Comment: Also... yes, do bring that code over to [codereview.se] (you'll want to use a title that ***describes the purpose of the code*** though) =)

Comment: As for your image link, just use the image uploader button in the [edit] box.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/154103/23788)